# initramfs-tools : Depends: initramfs-tools-bin (< 0.99ubuntu13.1.1~) but 0.99ubuntu13.4 is to be installed

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, apt-get

I have recently upgraded my Ubuntu 12.04 release to 'Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS' using

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I now need to remove phpmyadmin by doing the following

```
sudo apt-get remove phpmyadmin
```

However, I now get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
initramfs-tools : Depends: initramfs-tools-bin (< 0.99ubuntu13.1.1~) but 0.99ubuntu13.4 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

If I run 'apt-get -f install' I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgudev-1.0-0 gir1.2-gudev-1.0 openjdk-7-jre-lib
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  initramfs-tools
The following packages will be upgraded:
  initramfs-tools
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
11 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/49.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of initramfs-tools:
 initramfs-tools depends on initramfs-tools-bin (<< 0.99ubuntu13.1.1~); however:
  Version of initramfs-tools-bin on system is 0.99ubuntu13.4.
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of udev:
 udev depends on initramfs-tools (>= 0.92bubuntu63); however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing udev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dmsetup:
 dmsetup depends on initramfs-tools; however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
 dmsetup depends on udev (>> 141-2); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing dmsetup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apparmor:
 apparmor depends on initramfs-tools; however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing apparmor (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plymouth:
 plymouth depends on udev (>= 166-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.
 plymouth depends oNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                             No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
           n initramfs-tools; however:
  Package initramfs-tools is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing plymouth (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text:
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text depends on plymouth; however:
  Package plymouth is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libdevmapper1.02.1:
 libdevmapper1.02.1 depends on dmsetup (>= 2:1.02.48-4ubuntu7.4); however:
  Package dmsetup is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libdevmapper1.02.1 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-common:
 grub-common depends on libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.36); however:
  Package libdevmapper1.02.1 is not configured yet.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: error processing grub-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub2-common:
 grub2-common depends on grub-common (= 1.99-21ubuntu3.14); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing grub2-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-pc-bin:
 grub-pc-bin depends on libdevmapper1.02.1 (>= 2:1.02.36); however:
  Package libdevmapper1.02.1 is not configured yet.
 grub-pc-bin depends on grub-common (= 1.99-21ubuntu3.14); however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing grub-pc-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-pc:
 grub-pc depends on grub-common; however:
  Package grub-common is not configured yet.
 grub-pc depends on grub2-common (= 1.99-21ubuntu3.14); however:
  Package grub2-common is not configured yet.
 grub-pc depends on grub-pc-bin (= 1.99-21ubuntu3.14); however:
  Package grub-pc-bin is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing grub-pc (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
 udev
 dmsetup
 apparmor
 plymouth
 plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text
 libdevmapper1.02.1
 grub-common
 grub2-common
 grub-pc-bin
 grub-pc
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't know where to go from here, please can someone help?

Comment: Here you have the solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/367768/ubuntu-12-04-lts-initramfs-tools-dependency-issue

It worked for me